# im having a problem in installing and creating a new react js app

Tags: reactjs, installation, create-react-app, npm-install, npx

When i run this command line :

`npx create-react-app my_app`

this errors appears even that i have the latest version of nodejs :
[first part of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWRYS.png)

[second part of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEONe.png)

Comment: What version of Node are you using? Do you have nvm installed ? Please try with `yarn create react-app my_app` .

Comment: im using v16.15.0 and i dont have nvm, and for this command it showws another tunneling socket error

Comment: Ok, please try to remove any global installation of cra with : `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` then clear the cache with `npx clear-npx-cache` . Then try again with `npx create-react-app my_app` .

Comment: when i run the second command `npx clear-npx-cache` the same error appears (the one in the images )

Answer (score 0):

Read this Article in freecode camp carefully :https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/install-react-with-create-react-app/
=> If it was'nt work it, then check your node js intsallation. if node js is installed on your computer, make sure that your node version is 16.15.0(which means "Recommended for most users").
**Make Sure That watch the video carefully that given in article.**

Comment: i've done the same thing but still having the same error and for the node js i use the version 16.15.0

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, turn on/turn off the option "**Automatically detect settings**" on **Proxy** settings. Then, reopen cmd and try to install again.

[image: See the image here]